# Port forwarding local python server to access through mobile phone

Tags: portforwarding

I'm trying to test my personal website on my phone by setting up a local server and accessing it through my phone. So far I was able to successfully start the server on my VM by doing python3 -m http.server and accessing it from my VM through localhost port 8000 or by port forwarding to my host and accessing my website through there, by accessing port 8000.

I'm now trying to port forward through my router and access my test code from my phone but I seem unable to do it. I went in the single port forwarding options of my router's settings and in there I set up a rule to forward any incoming connections to port 8000 to my computer with port 8000. If I'm not mistaken, by writing my accessing 192.168.1.1:8000, the connection request should be transferred to my computer's 8000 port which in turn will transfer it to my VM's 8000 port, right? However, I seem unable to do it. Am I misunderstanding how the communication between ports is happening? Do I need to code a man in the middle to pass the connection request?

Thank you very much for your help, I hope that my question isn't too basic but so far this is the only way I can think of testing my code on my phone without pushing my changes to github pages.

TLDR;

how do I port forward my local servwe to access from my phone?
So far

host -> VM works
phone -> host doesn't work

Comment: Where are the host, VM and router located with respect to each other? On which machine does the test web site reside? To which machine does the 192.168.1.1 adddress belong to? Does your phone need to access your test web site from the Internet or from the same local network as the test web site?

Comment: VM is inside my host, its ip is 10.0.2.15. The port forwarding that I set up between VM and host is that when accessing port 8000 from 127.0.0.1 from my localhost, it will pass on to 10.0.2.15:8000. My host is connected to my router by ethernet and I set up a single port forwarding using the port 8000 so that theoretically I can access my host on port 8000 by accessing 192.168.1:8000 from my phone. Finally my phone is connected to the same router as well

Comment: So your host and phone are both located on your internal 192.168.1.0/24 network? And the router is just providing a bridge between your ethernet and WiFi (in addition to routing traffic to the external Internet)? Or are your ethernet and WiFi using different address ranges?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply but yes they are connected to the same network and the router is indeed supposed to be the bridge. The host is connected by ethernet to the router and the router is right next to me and my phone

Answer (score 0):

Since your host and phone are on the same 192.168.1.0/24 subnet, you do not need to configure anything on your router.

The port forwarding / network address translation needs to occur on your host. If your host has an IP of say 192.168.1.1 then your need to configure a port forwarding on the host as follows:

192.168.1.1:8000 to 10.0.2.15:8000